Installing a workspace package failed
I'm using NX and PNPM in a monorepo. I want to install a package inside one of my workspaces. I'm using this command to do so pnpm add --filter src/ --workspace --save-dev eslint-plugin-react.
I'm getting this error:
No projects matched the filters in "/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui"

Here is my pnpm-workspace.yml file:
# pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'src/*'
  - 'packages/*'


Make sure your yaml file is named exactly "pnpm-workspace.yaml". You mention a file with a yml extension, which will not work.
